# Realizar backup incremental o diferencial en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una base de datos que crece mucho constantemente, por ende debo cuidar mucho estos registros.

Estuve buscando en internet y Oracle Corporation (propietaria de MySQL desde 2010) proporciona un producto de pago, [MySQL Enterprise Backup](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/4.0/en/mysqlbackup.tasks.html), para realizar este tipo de backups con un comando, `mysqlbackups`.

Un ejemplo de uso:

```
mysqlbackup --backup-image=/backups/sales.mbi --backup-dir=/backup-tmp backup-to-image
```

Con esta herramienta existe la forma de realizar realizar backup incremental y realizar el backup diferencial.

Mi pregunta básicamente es: ¿Cómo realizar un backup incremental o diferencial con comandos básicos de MySQL?

Comment: Factorial? Te refieres a backup incremental?

Comment: incremental es que se basa en el backup anterior el factorial o diferencial se basa en el backup anterior mas los registros editados

Comment: ¿Pregunta basada en opiniones?

Comment: no, pregunta basica para DBA que algunos programadores como yo queremos saber

Comment: @JackNavaRow ¿Has pensado en la opción de crear un sistema de maestr/ esclavo y hacer backups de esclavo? De esa manera no "paras" la `BBDD` al hacer el backup (`LOCK TABLES`). Ahí te daría igual el tiempo que tarda el backup ya que no afecta a la `BBDD`. Si tu problema es otro ademas del tiempo, por favor amplia la pregunta para que pueda ayudarte.

Comment: tu idea es muy buena y me gusta pero no responde la pregunta ,tendria que hacer otra pregunta por que no he encontrado documentacion de lo que estas diciendo

Comment: Si quieres extiendo más la respuesta y te enseño como podría hacerse, del mismo modo, otra opción (siempre que tengas suficiente arquitectura para montarlo) es hacer un master-master-master de Galera: http://galeracluster.com/ yo lo tengo montado y es muy muy bueno.

Comment: Te he agregado una solución que podría valerte. En la actualidad la usamos para hacer backups de bases de datos de zabbix que contienen varios cientos de millones de registros en las tablas históricas y apenas afecta al rendimiento de la aplicación. Además, reducimos enormemente el tamaño de los backups usando incrementales diarios y completos semanales.

Comment: Lo que dice la [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/4.0/en/mysqlbackup.incremental.html)  aporta a mi parecer elementos interesantes a una posible respuesta.

Comment: ya lo habia leido me parece interesante pero es una version paga voy a modificar mi pregunta para luego cerrarla

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**¿Cómo realizar un backup incremental o diferencial con comandos básicos de MySQL?**

Se pueden hacer backups incrementales mediante las herramientas que provee MySQL, como `mysqldump`, usando posteriormente herramientas como `diff` para almacenar únicamente las diferencias.

El problema es que `mysqldump` tiene varios problemas para un uso empresarial:

- El proceso de backup sobrecarga la CPU y memoria debido a la forma en la que se obtienen los datos. Se lanzan diferentes consulta SQL al servidor y éste debe procesar los resultados para enviarlos a `mysqldump`. A su vez `mysqldump` debe recoger esa información y guardarla siguiente un formato SQL para poder reproducirlo posteriormente.
- El tamaño de los backups es bastante mayor a de los datos en disco. En el caso de tablas con datos binarios (blobs) se vuelcan en hexadecimal.
- Un proceso posterior o simultáneo (mediante el uso de tuberías) de compresión aumentaría el tiempo de backup o la carga del procesador y el de restauración porque habría que realizar el proceso de descompresión.
- La duración del backup es extremadamente elevado comparado con el equivalente de la lectura de los datos directamente desde el disco.
- La restauración es extremadamente lenta comparado con el equivalente de escritura directa en disco.
- Aunque la herramienta proporciona opciones como [`--single-transaction`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) para hacer backups consistentes a nivel de base de datos, ésta no es robusta (*) y puede bloquear el acceso a todas las tablas y bases de datos del servidor si el log de transacciones se llena durante volcados de gran cantidad de registros hasta que se finalice la transacción del backup.
- Opciones como [`--lock-tables`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_lock-tables) bloquean el uso de las tablas durante el volcado, provocando bloqueo en las consultas en dichas tablas.
- El proceso de restauración sobrecarga la CPU, disco y memoria del servidor debido a la interpretación y validación de cada consulta SQL realizada y provocado también por la comprobación de las claves en la inserción de cada registro, cada vez mayor cuantos más registros se han insertado (aunque puede reducirse el impacto usando opciones como [`--disable-keys`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_disable-keys)).

(*) [De la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction):

> While a `--single-transaction` dump is in process, to ensure a valid
>   dump file (correct table contents and binary log coordinates), no
>   other connection should use the following statements: `ALTER TABLE`,
>   `CREATE TABLE`, `DROP TABLE`, `RENAME TABLE`, `TRUNCATE TABLE`. A consistent
>   read is not isolated from those statements, **so use of them on a table
>   to be dumped can cause the `SELECT` that is performed by mysqldump to
>   retrieve the table contents to obtain incorrect contents or fail**.

El uso de `ALTER TABLE`, `CREATE TABLE`, `DROP TABLE`, `RENAME TABLE`, `TRUNCATE TABLE` durante un backup podría obtener resultados incorrectos o provocar su fallo.

---

## Solución propuesta

Si puedes hacer uso de otra herramienta (completamente gratuita, a diferencia de la de MySQL) te recomiendo usar la herramienta de backup desarrollada por Percona llamada [XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup):

> Percona XtraBackup is a free, open source, complete online backup solution for all versions of Percona Server for MySQL, MySQL ® and MariaDB®. With over 2,100,000 downloads, Percona XtraBackup performs online non-blocking, tightly compressed, highly secure backups on transactional systems so that applications remain fully available during planned maintenance windows.

En castellano:

> Percona XtraBackup es una solución completa de backup gratuita, de código abierto para todas las versiones de Percona Server, MySQL® and MariaDB®. Con más de 2.100.000 descargas, Percona XtraBackup realiza copias de seguridad en línea sin bloqueo, fuertemente comprimidas y altamente seguras en sistemas transaccionales para que las aplicaciones permanezcan totalmente disponibles durante las ventanas de mantenimiento planificadas.

O, lo que es lo mismo, el rendimiento de la base de datos se degrada levemente durante el backup pero no se realiza ningún bloqueo de tablas ni interfiere con el trabajo habitual del servidor.

En [la documentación sobre backups incrementales](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/LATEST/backup_scenarios/incremental_backup.html) puedes ver un ejemplo de uso:

Para realizar un backup completo basta con ejecutar:

```
xtrabackup --backup --target-dir=/data/backups/base
```

Para realizar un backup incremental a partir del anterior:

```
xtrabackup --backup --target-dir=/data/backups/incremental1 \
    --incremental-basedir=/data/backups/base
```

**Funcionamiento**

En la [página web del producto](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/how_xtrabackup_works.html) aparece con detalle el proceso.

Realiza una copia binaria de los archivos de disco, reduciendo al mínimo el impacto al servidor, analizando el log de transacciones para marcar el punto exacto de inicio (el `LSN` o número de secuencia del log) y, por lo tanto, poder proporcionar un backup completamente consistente, al tiempo que actualiza en segundo plano los datos del log.

Los backups diferenciales trabajan copiando únicamente las diferencias almacenadas en el log de transacciones, reduciendo el acceso a disco y el tiempo del backup.

Como única pega decirte que las tablas MyISAM no pueden ser guardadas de forma incremental porque no son transaccionales, por lo que se hace la copia completa de ellas realizando un bloqueo de tablas.

Hoy en día no hay motivo de peso para mantener tablas en MyISAM, por lo que esto no debería suponer un problema.

Al restaurar el backup se fuerza una recuperación para que se actualice la información de las tablas hasta donde llegue el log de transacciones (*crash recovery*), por lo que la recuperación también tendrá como resultado una restauración consistente a nivel de base de servidor completo (y no a nivel de base de datos como haría el modo "en una transacción").

Además, como la restauración se hace en un directorio diferente (que luego hay que mover al de producción) se puede ejecutar un servidor MySQL en un puerto diferente para que acceda a los datos restaurados.

Puede ser útil para probarlos o acceder a ellos para hacer un acceso puntual a algún dato borrado o hacer una exportación o recuperación selectiva.

**Desventajas**

Si las tablas no están optimizadas (tienen "residuo para depurar", registros modificados o borrados que dejan los valores viejos ocupando espacio sin ser usado) durante el backup se copiará el residuo al backup completo (pero no al incremental), por lo que es recomendable ejecutar un `OPTIMIZE TABLE` a aquellas tablas de mayor tamaño o que suelan acumular un residuo mayor antes de un backup completo.

## Backup a través de LVM

Otra manera de realizar un backup consistente es mediante [snapshots LVM](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html).

Todo el contenido de MySQL debería almacenarse en el mismo volumen lógico para que esta solución fuera aplicable (logs de transacciones, logs de replicación si los hubiera, espacios de tablas, etc).

Durante el proceso de recuperación se debería forzar una [*recuperación de caída*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html) para que se hiciera `rollback` de todas aquellas transacciones que no se completaron en el instante del backup.

El proceso se realizaría de la siguiente manera:

```
# Creamos un LV para el snapshot
lvcreate -L1G -n mysqlbackup -s mysqldatos
```

Donde:

- `-L1G` permite que se modifique la partición original 1 GB antes de que éste se llene. Si la actividad de la base de datos es alta es probable que se requiera de un snapshot más grande.
- `-n mysqlbackup` pondrá el nombre `mysqlbackup` a este volumen lógico.
- `-s mysqldatos` indica que será un snapshot del volumen lógico `mysqldatos`.

Para montar el snapshot y acceder a él para almacenarlo o calcular el backup incremental:

```
# Averiguamos el nombre del dispositivo donde se ha creado el volumen lógico
lvdisplay | egrep "LV Path*mysqlbackup$"
# Creamos el punto de montaje (si no existe)
[ -d /mnt/mysqlbackup ] || mkdir /mnt/mysqlbackup
# Montamos el snapshot
mount /dev/mapper/vg-mysqlbackup /mnt/ops/mysqlbackup
# [hacemos el backup del tipo que sea]
# ...
# Desmontamos y borramos el snapshot
umount /mnt/ops/mysqlbackup
lvremove /dev/mapper/vg-mysqlbackup
```

La herramienta para gestionar backups completos e incrementales a partir del snapshot podría ser [`duplicity`](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/), que soporta el backup incremetal de archivos grandes almacenando únicamente las partes modificadas desde el backup anterior.

Comment: esta herramienta permite backups con otros tipos de base de datos? se que mi pregunta es en base a mysql pero creo que seria util para otras personas saber con que base de datos aparte de MariaDB y MySQL funcionaria

Comment: Tal y como pongo en las citas, es compatible con todos los motores soportados por MySQL, Percona Server y MariaDB. Por ejemplo MyISAM, InnoDB, XtraDB, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Hace un tiempo estuve buscando por la escuela y por un proyecto que tenia que es eso.

**Backup incremental de tu base de datos con Git**

Una forma realmente interesante de realizar backups de tus bases de datos (por ser trivial y muy potente) es usando Git. El proceso es simple y se basa en la realización de los dumps de la base de datos de forma que cada fila de las tablas sea un insert aislado, de esa forma en cada commit solo estaremos salvando las diferencias respecto al último estado (tanto deletes como inserts, como updates).

En el caso concreto de MySQL inicialmente haríamos algo como esto:

```
$ mkdir mydatabase && cd mydatabase
$ mysqldump --skip-extended-insert > data.sql
$ git init
$ git add data.sql
$ git commit -m "Initial dump of mydatabase"
```

A partir de entonces podemos automatizar el proceso con un script tan simple como este:

```
$ cat /usr/bin/git_backup_database!/bin/sh
BACKUP_DIRECTORY=$1
DATABASE=$2

cd $BACKUP_DIRECTORY &&
mysqldump --skip-extended-insert $DATABASE > data.sql &&
git commit -am "Updating dump `date +%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M`"`
```

Según el volumen de consultas que tenga tu base de datos, te será interesante ponerlo en cron con una frecuencia determina u otra. Adicionalmente sería recomendable ejecutar $ git gc para optimizar el repositorio. Por ejemplo, dos veces al día y una vez a la semana mantenimiento:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/git_backup_database /path/to/mydatabase mydatabase
0 12 * * * /usr/bin/git_backup_database  /path/to/mydatabase mydatabase
0 1 * * 1 cd /path/to/mydatabase && git gc
```

Además desde otro equipo nadie te impide hacer un `$ git clone ssh://equipo:path/to/mydatabase` y tener todo el historial de la base de datos en un plis (bueno eso es relativo, que ocupará lo suyo…) o incluso programar un $ git pull para tener varios backups en distintas maquinas. En definitiva, se abren un sinfín de opciones .

Comment: Hola Jose Crush, en lugar de solo dejar un enlace deberías colocar la respuesta aquí directamente. Dejar solo un link sin más explicación no es considerada una buena respuesta en este sitio. Lee la parte que dice **Ofrece contexto para los enlaces** de [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Una disculpa soy nuevo en esta pagina y no habia entendido muy bien lo del contexto para los enlaces. Leere ese apartado y editare mi respuesta para que pueda ayudar. Gracias

Comment: @JoseCrush Gracias Jose son importantes los consejos de Carlos y Toledano para que tu respuesta tenga una calidad aceptada en el sitio, saludos y bienvenido!

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys tomare en cuenta sus consejos para poder responder y preguntar de una buena manera. Saludos!

Comment: Siento darte un -1, pero los backups con `mysqldump` no son consistentes y es probable que bloquee tablas. Una base de datos histórica (datos de monitorización, auditoría, etc) de varios millones de registros provocaría que un commit se eternizara. ¿Has comprobado la escalabilidad de esta solución?

Answer (score 4):

Como hemos comentado en los comentarios, creo que tienes una opción que hasta ahora no se ha contemplado, que es hacer trabajar a la plataforma en vez de buscar una solución algo más "manual".

Tu problema es que crece mucho la `BBDD` y entiendo que lo que no quieres hacer es un `backup` que constantemente esté bloqueando la `BBDD`.

Te puedo dar 3 soluciones, dependiendo de lo que necesites o te puedas permitir a nivel de plataforma, te recomiendo una u otra, en este caso te las pongo en orden de complejidad/coste para la aplicación.

## Master/Slave de MySQL

En este caso lo que tenemos es un un `master de MySQL` y un `slave` de esa maquina. De esta manera, mientras puedes seguir escribiendo en el `master`, el `slave` tiene una copia completa de la `BBDD` de la que solo puedes leer, pero que puedes bloquear tantas veces como quieras y a la que puedes machacar sin pudor ninguno, ya que los `updates` los ira obteniendo a medida que pueda.

Montarlo es relativamente sencillo, te dejo un tutorial de [como instalar un `master/slave de MySQL`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql)

Aunque controles poco de ingles, con seguir los comandos es suficiente. Yo lo tengo en una aplicación muy grande en producción y ningún problema.

Lo bueno que tiene es que se puede montar con dos maquinas, por lo tanto el gasto en plataforma es bastante pequeño y lo puedes ampliar tanto como quieras. El número de lecturas es muy alto y el de escrituras tan alto como te permita el `master`. Del mismo modo, si se cae el `slave` no pasa nada y si se cae el `master` puedes cambiar el `slave` a `master` y salvar la aplicación.

## Cluster de MySQL

Es una característica nueva de la versión `5.7` que solo he podido probar con un proyecto de prueba por lo que no te puedo dar un feedback extremadamente bueno, solo decirte que parece que lo ha probado mucho y las opiniones que he visto son bastante favorables.

Aquí tienes el [tutorial para instalar un `cluster de MySQL`](http://lefred.be/content/mysql-innodb-cluster-mysql-shell-starter-guide/), no es tan sencillo como un `master/slave` pero te da muchas más cosas que él. Por ejemplo tiene `automatic sharding` que te permite aumentar muchísimo el número de escrituras. Si no sabes lo que es `sharding`, lo comentan en [StackOverflow en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992988/what-is-sharding-and-why-is-it-important), seguro que la lectura te ayuda.

## Galera Cluster

Es un `cluster` de `master/master/master` esto es, puedes leer y escribir de los tres servidores a la vez, creo que es demasiado para lo que tu necesitas pero si te plateas que la aplicación puede aumentar mucho de tamaño es muy buena opción.

El problema es que mínimo tienen que existir 3 servidores para que el `cluster` sea lo suficientemente consistente, ya que debe de existir lo que se llama [`quorum`](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/weightedquorum.html). El número de lecturas no aumenta tanto como en un `cluster de MySQL` porque no tiene el `automatic sharding` pero a diferencia de `master/slave` puede caer un servidor sin ningún tipo de problema porque el `quorum` puede seguir existiendo.

Aquí tienes como [instalar galera en CentOS7](https://www.debyum.com/setup-mariadb-galera-cluster-in-centos-7/) e [instalar galera en Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-galera-cluster-with-mariadb-10-1-on-ubuntu-16-04-servers), como no se que sistema usas, te dejo los dos. Yo siempre prefiero `CentOS` o `Debian` para todo lo relacionado con servidores.

## Diferencias entre `Galera` y `MySQL Cluster`

Las diferencias entre `Galera` y el clustes de `Mysql` son bastantes, te recomiendo que te leas [este slideshare](https://severalnines.com/blog/galera-cluster-mysql-vs-mysql-ndb-cluster-high-level-comparison-webinar-replay-slides), ya que si lo ponemos aquí la respuesta seria casi infinita y luego entrarían las opiniones de cada uno de que es mejor o peor.

Creo que con esto te puedo dar una idea de las opciones que tienes a nivel de plataforma, sin tener que tirar de cosas algo más "extrañas" como ponerle un `git` a un fichero de `MySQL`

Si necesitas ampliar algo más de información comentalo y te ayudo en lo que pueda.