# Extraer de forma automatizada datos relacionados de varias tablas

Tags: sql, script

Me he tenido que enfrentar a este problema hace poco y solucionarlo de manera manual es tedioso y evitar errores por omisión no es sencillo:

### Escenario:

**Precondiciones:**

Tengo una tabla TRABAJO con una PK numérica que se autoincrementa. Es la tabla *maestra* que tiene varias tablas asociadas:

- HISTORIAL: Guarda todas las acciones realizadas sobre un trabajo.
- MENSAJES: Guarda todas las comunicaciones de un trabajo.
- ADJUNTOS: Guarda todos los archivos adjuntos a un trabajo.
- TAREAS: Un trabajo puede tener subtareas especificas que se guardan aquí.
- ... Unas 5 tablas más relacionadas con TRABAJO por una FK.

**Problema**:
Un usuario borró por error un trabajo y la aplicación cuando borra, lo hace de verdad y en cascada (*disclaimer*: no es mi implementación, estamos trabajando en modificar esta parte para hacer borrados lógicos).

**Mi solución**
La solución fue tirar de backup: monté una base de datos temporal en otra máquina y busqué el trabajo borrado para volver a insertarlo. Pero tuve que buscar, tabla por tabla, el resto de registros relacionados, copiarlos a un fichero de texto en formato CSV y crear las instrucciones insert para cada registro e insertarlos por orden.

**Mi pregunta** es: ¿Existe alguna forma de, dado una ID de la tabla principal, extraer todos los datos relacionados para insertarlos en otra base de datos con el mismo esquema de un modo automatizado? Para mi lo ideal sería crear un ficheros con todos los `insert` listos para ser ejecutados.

En mi caso trabajo con PostgreSQL, pero se aceptan ideas para cualquier gestor de bases de datos o scripts de línea de comandos.

Comment: Se recomienda desactivar las acciones en cascada de las relaciones, con esto te quitas un grave problema. Lo otro seguramente con un procedimiento almacenado y una estructura bien definida bajo un standard estricto para el nombrado de TABLES, PK y FK puede que se logre. O apoyarte en el ORM que generalmente tiene toda esa logica relacional y una forma más facil de trabajar.

Comment: puedes hacer servidores espejos pero igual no te protege de los usuarios. lo ideal es realizar [backups incrementales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529603/best-method-for-postgresql-incremental-backup) y tambien aplicar servidores espejos eso dependera de cuanto quiera pagar la empresa

Comment: Pregunta relacionada : [realizar backup-incremental o diferencial en mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56041/realizar-backup-incremental-o-diferencial-en-mysql)

Comment: Igual te puede servir algo como [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/)

Comment: Creo que hay muchas soluciones para respaldar la información de tus tablas/bases de datos. mi propuesta y de una manera muy rudimentaria pero rápida, seria utilizar triggers en las tablas que te interesa auditar y para que guarde dentro de otra base de datos basta con que generes sinónimos de las bases de datos y tablas a las que quieres apuntar.

Comment: Si el problema es el borrado "físico", lo que yo haría sería "_hook-ear_" el `INSERT` y `UPDATE` para que estos se realicen en ambas DBs al mismo tiempo. De esta forma te asegurarías de estar siempre actualizado y "_backup-eado_". En el caso del `DELETE`, si ya están migrando a borrado lógico, también; sino, el _hook_ debería implementarse para hacerlo de forma lógica solo en DB de respaldo.

Comment: Yo procedería exactamente del modo que vos indicaste: haría la inserción de la tabla principal, obtendría el ID y lo propagaría al resto de los tablas relacionadas.
Todo esto en un script donde cada línea sería un INSERT.
En el caso de SQL Server se podría hacer alternativamente una snapshot periódicamente a modo de backup.

Answer (score 1):

Existen varias soluciones.

1. Puedes Quitar restricciones como DELETE CASCADE y sustiturlo por UPDATE CASCADE.
   2)Puedes implementar la solución con la tabla tempopral y crear un trigger que capture todos los insert Realizados en la tabla principal e insertarlos de manera automatica en la tabla temporal o backup. Pero seria trabajar de manera duplicada, cuando el objetivo siempre debe ser simplificar los procesos. Yo te recomiendo realizar eliminación lógica.
   Agregando un status, puede ser enum(1,0), o enum('activo','inactivo') en la tabla TRABAJO

Answer (score 0):

Yo no soy partidario de eliminaciones en tablas, y menos en cascada, si de lo que se trata es de que no sea operativo ese registro con lo que le cuelga, lo que hago es cambiarlo de estado, utilizando un campo para ello, a partir de aquí

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Realmente lo expuesto, parece más bien una opinión para trasladar en un comentario, de acuerdo a como funciona este sitio, que una respuesta. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer].