# Pasar datos de una tabla de un servidor, a otra tabla de otro servidor

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo dos servidores con las mismas bases de datos y las mismas tablas, 
cual es la mejor y mas optima manera de pasar datos de una tabla de un servidor a una tabla de otro servidor

Comment: Muchas buenas preguntas generan cierto grado de opinión según la experiencia de los expertos, pero casi todas las respuestas a esta pregunta estarán basadas en opiniones, en lugar de hechos, referencias o experiencia específica, por lo tanto, su pregunta puede ser cerrada.

Comment: puedes ver una [respuesta mas completa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56041/realizar-backup-incremental-o-diferencial-en-mysql) ya hecha es mysql pero las herramientas no cambian

Comment: @JackNavaRow La respuesta a la que lo diriges no tiene relación con esta pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma óptima de transferir datos entre servidores varia según la infraestructura de cada lugar. Aquí dejo 3 opciones básicas.

1. Linked Server

   - Proporciona un ambiente completamente dentro de SQL Server que se manejará con T-SQL. Es una de las opciones que se evitan más por cuestiones de seguridad y sólo se permite para usuarios especializados (DBAs y desarrolladores Sr.).
2. bcp y BULK INSERT

   - Es una opción muy rápida y que consume muy pocos recursos. La exportación es por medio de línea de comandos y genera un archivo de texto que debe transferirse al servidor de destino para que se pueda importar. Esta opción permite un control mayor de la seguridad y puede permitir un registro de la información transferida. Tiene opciones para manejo de errores y flexibilidad para importar y exportar. El mayor problema es que la documentación no es muy clara y requiere comprenderse de forma adecuada para prevenir errores.
3. SSIS

   - Es la herramienta para transmisión de datos más recomendada por Microsoft. La flexibilidad es muy grande, pero la curva de aprendizaje también. Es tan eficiente que ha roto records de velocidad de transmisión de datos.

Cualquiera de las opciones presentadas tiene pros y contras. Sin tener un esquema claro de lo que se va a hacer, la decisión será de quien tenga que desarrollar la solución.

Comment: Hola, Luis Cazares cree un paquete con SSIS transmiten los datos como yo quiero, solo que cada vez que se ejecuta el paquete vuelve y los replica  "pero existen datos en la tabla destino que ya existen en la tabla origen, que condición puedo hacer"

Comment: Creo que eso debería ser parte de otra pregunta. Recuerda seguir las normas para que no cierren las preguntas que hagas.