# Replicación de SQL Server (Local) a MySql (Remoto)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, server, mysqldb

Hola tengo un programita de una tienda cuya base de datos la gestiona con SQL Server y tengo en un servidor un una aplicación web con MySql la cual quiero que se actualice con el stock de la base de datos local (Cada 5 min p.e) solo necesitaría alguna tabla no es necesario que sea entera.

Me gustaría saber si esto es posible y con que medios porque no me queda nada claro si necesitaría un software intermediario.

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Realizar backup incremental o diferencial en MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56041/realizar-backup-incremental-o-diferencial-en-mysql)

Comment: la idea es que crees o un script o que tengas base de datos espejos para que automaticamente se pase la info

Comment: Pero él dice que los bases de datos son diferentes, uno es SQL, el otro es MySQL.  No es tan fácil como backup o restore.

Comment: Quizás un script en python que conecte las dos he visto algo por ahí ahora mismo no tengo mucha idea voy a investigar esa lineal.  Solo necesitaría hacer un Update de la local cada 5 min por ejemplo para controlar el stock. Gracias Jack! Le hecho un ojo y actualizo!

Comment: @Duston claro es de SQL server a MySql según he leído mis opciones son la siguientes sin indagar en ninguna, Un script, servicios en la nube tipo Azure o AWS o un software de terceros que haga de intermediario siendo estas dos últimas de coste.